# SSO spring boot y wso2 is

Tags: spring-boot, wso2

Hola estoy corriendo este ejemplo pero con el wso2-is:4.5.1
https://github.com/nicodewet/template-spring-boot-oauth2-wso2-is
y aunque ya agrege el certificado q genera el wso2 a mi jdk me sigue saliendo el error en mi pagina:

> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing
>   this as a fallback.
>
> ```
> Wed May 16 10:57:21 GMT-04:00 2018
> There was an unexpected error (type=Unauthorized, status=401).
> Authentication Failed: Could not obtain access token
> ```

pero la consola del wso2 is no da error solo muestra este info

> INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.config.OAuthServerConfiguration}
>   -  The default Identity OAuth token issuer will be used. No custom token generator is set.

Comment: estas usando el modo DEBUG para que te imprima todos los logs en la aplicacion web y además estás usando el proxy HTTPS inverso como te recomiendan para ver todo el tráfico entre la webapp y el WSO2 IS? Con los logs generados y la data intercambiada se podria saber que pasa.

Comment: no he usado nada de eso, porque queria ir por paso y no perderme. Yo creo q si hay intercambio entre el IS y la app porque puedo autenticarme pero cuando apruebo los permisos de la aplicacion sobre los datos del perfil me direcciona para mi app pero sale el error y no me redireccion para la pagina de logueado